# Get all entry where term id equal Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

**News**

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------+
| news_id |     title     |     short     |     body     | etc... |
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------+
|  881971 | Article Title | Article short | Article Body |        |
|  881972 | Article Title | Article short | Article Body |        |
|  881973 | Article Title | Article short | Article Body |        |
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------+
```

**Term**

```
+-----+--------------+
| tid | news_term_id |
+-----+--------------+
|  14 |       881971 |
|   2 |       881972 |
|   2 |       881973 |
+-----+--------------+
```

I need select all from table **News** where **tid** in **Term** equal 2 (for example)
Trying like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM news, term
WHERE news.news_id = term.tid 
GROUP BY term.tid
```

But is not what i need. Its like blog articles with categoryes, need select all articles where category id 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select n.*, t.*
from news n
inner join term t 
    on n.news_id = t.news_term_id 
    and t.tid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM news, term
WHERE news.news_id = **term.news_term_id  AND term.tid=2**
GROUP BY term.tid